# Deleting pointers and map in destructor

Tags: c++

Suppose a class contains pointers and map of strings. In the destructor, apart from deleting the pointers, should we also clear the map or would this be automatically done?

Comment: depends how you declare it

Answer (score 2):

If you have a member variable like `std::map<>` (that you've stack-allocated) then you can rely on its destructor when your class destructs. The standard mandates that `std::map` will release all its memory once it's destroyed.

If you declare it as a pointer and you have used `new`, then you ought to use `delete` in your destructor. Just be careful not to have any exceptions thrown in your destructor as that will cause memory faults.

Comment: What happens when I have a pointer of user defined type and a map. Should I free the map as well in the destructor apart from the pointer or it would suffice to only delete the pointer?

Comment: @mickeyj: It would be an idea to re-submit a question with an actual class definition. That way, you'll get clear answers.